# Why these resistors on the Pololu MC33926 carrier?

Tags: h-bridge

I'm trying to design a motor driver carrier for the DRV8873 chip, and I've been looking at Pololu's motor driver carriers as reference material. I noticed that they have inserted 1k resistors on all of the control lines. The datasheet says nothing about these. Help me understand why these are needed in this application.

[image: Pololu MC33926 Carrier Schematic]

Bonus: does the DRV8873 have protection features which would remove the need to insert a reverse polarity protection circuit?

Comment: It's probably just to protect the pin in case they are wired incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

A 1Kohm resistor, against 5pF onchip ESD + Schmidtt noise_immunity circuit, would cause about 5 nanoseconds delay.

If 5nS is well within the timing budget, then 1Kohm is a good value for surviving lots of external MISWIRE and ESD events.